# How to show that $\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1-x^3}\right)\;dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral: $$ \int_0^1 \left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1-x^3}\right)\;dx$$

The answer is $0,$ but I am unable to get it. There is some symmetry I can not see.

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\int_0^1 \sqrt[m]{1-x^n}dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt[n]{1-x^m}dx = \frac{\frac{1}{m} ! \cdot \frac{1}{n} !}{\left(\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n}\right) !}$$ where $$\frac{1}{n} ! = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx$$ See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_May_7#Linking_Factorials_to_Geometric_Shapes) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_June_10#Basic_Demonstration_Required) for more details.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Let $m, n > 0$. Then observe that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^m} \; dx$$
is the area of the region given by inequalities
$$ 0 \leq x \leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt[n]{1-x^m}.$$
But the last inequality is equivalent to $0 \leq x^m + y^n \leq 1$. Thus
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^m} \; dx = [\text{Area given by} \ 0 \leq x^m + y^n \leq 1, \ 0 \leq x, y \leq 1 ]$$
Thus by interchanging the role of $x$ and $y$, we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{1-x^m} \; dx = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[m]{1-x^n} \; dx.$$

---

Of course, we can give a purely analytic approach. Let $y = \sqrt[3]{1 - x^7}$. Then $x = \sqrt[7]{1 - y^3}$ and hence by integration by substitution,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{1 - x^7} \; dx
&= \int_{0}^{1} y(x) \; dx \\
&= \int_{1}^{0} y \; dx(y) \\
&= [y x(y)]_{1}^{0} - \int_{1}^{0} x(y) \; dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[7]{1 - y^3} \; dy.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Formally (and not only formally), we know that $d(xy)=x\, dy + y \, dx$ Hence $xy = \int x \, dy + y \, dx$. This is an abstract way to compute the integral of a function provided we know the integral of its inverse.

Comment: @Siminore: The way you demonstrated is very clear and systematic. All the scattered understandings on this kind of integral are now integrated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is to use [$\beta$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

> $$ \mathrm{\beta}(x,y) = \int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt,\quad {Re}(x),{Re(y)}>0.  $$

$$ \int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{1-x^7} \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{7}\int_0^1 u^{-6/7}(1-u)^{1/3} \mathrm dx=\dots\,. $$

Now, you can finish the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Observing the inverse of the function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 - x^7}$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is $f^{-1} (x) = \sqrt[7]{1 - x^3}$, using the [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions)
$$\int^b_a f(x) \, dx + \int^{f(b)}_{f(a)} f^{-1} (x) \, dx = b f(b) - a f(a),$$
since $f(a) = f(0) = 1$ and $f(b) = f(1) = 0$ it immediately follows that
$$\int^1_0 \sqrt[3]{1 - x^7} \, dx + \int^0_1 \sqrt[7]{1 - x^3} \, dx = 0,$$
or
$$\int^1_0 \left \{\sqrt[3]{1 - x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1 - x^3} \right \}\, dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, let’s denote $$I(m, n)=\frac{1}{m} \int_0^1 y^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-y)^{\frac{1}{m}-1} d y$$

Using the substitution $y=1-x^m$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n)&=\frac{1}{m} \int_0^1 y^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-y)^{\frac{1}{m}-1} d y \\&=\frac{1}{m} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+1\right)} \\
& =\frac{1}{m n} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\\&=I(n,m)
\end{aligned}
$$

So

> $$I(m,n)-I(n,m)=0 \Rightarrow \int_0^1 \left(\sqrt[m]{1-x^n} - \sqrt[n]{1-x^m}\right)\;dx = 0 $$