# How to integrate $\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt[3]{x^7+1}-\sqrt[7]{x^3+1}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show that $\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1-x^3}\right)\;dx = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139393/how-to-show-that-int-01-left-sqrt31-x7-sqrt71-x3-right-dx)

Any hints one how to start?

I have shown $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}-\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}\, dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{1-(1-x)^7}-\sqrt[7]{1-(1-x)^3}\, dx$$
but I don't know how to proceed. Wolfram tells me the result is $0$ and that $\int\sqrt[3]{x^7+1}-\sqrt[7]{x^3+1}\, dx$ has a very complicated closed form

Comment: See [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139393/how-to-show-that-int-01-left-sqrt31-x7-sqrt71-x3-right-dx/139398#139398)

Comment: @tetori So simple. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!